# Как найти определенные буквы в строке?

Tags: c

Есть строка символов. Как определить входят ли в строку пара соседствующих символов "он" или "но":

```
/*Программа работает с массивом символов*/
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void Rus_1251(char* in, char* out)
{
  int len = strlen(in);
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    unsigned char simb = (*in);
    if((simb>=128)&&(simb<=175))
      simb += 64;
    else
    if((simb>=224)&&(simb<=239))
      simb += 16;
    *out = simb;
    out++;
    in++;
  }
}
int main()
{
   setlocale (0, "rus");
   int CountLit = 0, CountSpace = 0;
    char str[300];
    do {
        cout << "Введите строку: "; //повторять ввод строки пока первый символ равен (!)
        gets_s(str,300);
        if(str[0] == '!')
            cout << "Первый символ строки <!>" << endl;
    } while (str[0] == '!');
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '!')
        {
            str[i] = 0; //і-тый элемент (восклицательный знак) становится концом строки
            break;
        }
    }
    Rus_1251(str,str);
    cout << "Cтрока до первого <!>: " << str << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == ' ')
            CountSpace++;
        if (str[i] == 'ю')
            CountLit++;
    }
    cout << "Количество пробелов = " << CountSpace << endl;
    if (CountLit != 0)
        cout << "Буква 'ю' входит в строку" << endl;
    else {
        cout << "Буква 'ю' не входит в строку" << endl;
    }
    if(strchr(str ,'ш') != 0 && strchr(str ,'и') != 0 && strchr(str ,'н') != 0 && strchr(str ,'а') != 0)
        cout << "В строке есть все буквы, входящие в слово 'шина'" << endl;
    else{
        cout << "В строке есть не все буквы, входящие в слово 'шина'" << endl;}
    char str1[5] = {'н','о', 'Н','О'};
    char str2[5] = {'о','н', 'О','н'};
    if(strstr(str, str1) == NULL || strstr(str, str2) == NULL)
        cout << "В строке нет подстроки 'он' или 'но' " << endl;
    else{
        cout << "В строке есть подстрока 'он' или 'но' " << endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Функция strstr в помощь

Comment: if(strstr("но", str) != 0 || strstr("но", str) != 0) //я пробовал - не работает

Comment: Осталось разобраться с кодировками...

Comment: Разъясните, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, для поиска подстроки в строке используется библиотечная функция [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr):

```
char str[] = "At any rate, I am convinced that He [God] does not play dice.";
printf("%s\n", strstr(str, "I am")); // --> I am convinced that He [God] does not play dice.
```

Функция возвращает указатель на первый символ подстроки или `NULL`, если подстрока не найдена. Функция `strstr` чувствительна к регистру символов, по этому, например, строка `"i am"` не будет найдена.

---

В случае с кириллицей дело обстоит сложнее. Можно использовать аналог `strstr` для широких символов — функцию [`wcsstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcsstr):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    wchar_t str[5][64] = {
        L"Строка, где есть подстрока 'но'.",
        L"Строка, где такой подстроки нет.",
        L"Он здесь.",
        L"Здесь он.",
        L"Его нет."
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (wcsstr(str[i], L"но") || wcsstr(str[i], L"он")) {
            wprintf(L"%s\n", str[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
Строка, где есть подстрока 'но'.
Здесь он.
```

Вообще, работа с Unicode в C тема обширная и выходит за рамки вопроса.